# Best CMS for managing user collections?

Tags: cms, collection-manager

I'd like to build a site for action figure collectors. Users should be able to register accounts, search for items, view items, mark items as "owned" or "wanted".

Are there any good off-the-shelf solutions for this? Ideally some sort of theme or other product that I can just buy, install and get to customizing. I'm familiar with Wordpress and Drupal.

Comment: I wonder if this question is appropriate here on Software Recommendations or on WebApps (or both).  Are you looking for software or a web-based solution?

Comment: I was hoping for something web-based. Or possibly some sort of BuddyPress or WooCommerce custom theme, since those tools are functionally similar to what I want to do.

Comment: Drupal is really good in distribution as said also have a look at wildapricot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Drupal, I think your question is best addressed by what Drupal calls a [Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution). Quote from that link:

> Distributions provide site features and functions for a specific type of site as a single download containing Drupal core, contributed modules, themes, and pre-defined configuration. They make it possible to quickly set up a complex, use-specific site in fewer steps than if installing and configuring elements individually.

Checkout the [list of 11 distributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=drupal_core%3A103&f%5B3%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=collection&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search) to pick from (in which I used keyword "collection"). There doesn't seem to be any specific fit, but I think these 2 might be worth considering (quotes are from the linked pages):

- [Totem](https://www.drupal.org/project/totem) (attention: needs some security fixes):

> ... a packaged distribution designed for organizations that want to build **communities of users who have very specific interests** and who want to share topical discussions, media and events with their peers.

- [DruStack](https://www.drupal.org/project/drustack):

> ... A collection of most common software from the Drupal community, DruStack provides **a quick on-ramp to begin building Drupal websites**.